# Intro to Numerical Methods

Tags: numerical-methods

What is the gap between $2$ and the next larger double-precision number? 
I understand to do this it is $2^{-52} \cdot 2^1 = 2^{-51}$

I'm having a little more difficulty with this one though. 
What is the gap between $201$ and the next larger double-precision number?

Comment: What exponent is used when representing $201$?

Answer (score 0):

You can experiment with it [here](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html). It is single precision but will give you a sufficient idea how 201 is represented, and what is the next larger double-precision number.